# Converting PHP array into JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, variables

I need to convert my php array into a javascript variable.  I am using json_encode to do this but it is returning with some errors.  I have a php variable:

```
<?php $damage_array = $listing->tire_detail->damage_details; ?>
```

which prints out to be

```
Array ( [lf] => 4 [rf] => 9 [lrfo] => 22 [rrfo] => 19 [lrfi] => 22 [rrfi] => 19 [lrro] => 15 [rrro] => 10 [lrri] => 15 [rrri] => 10 )
```

Then in my javascript I have:

```
var damages = "<?php echo json_encode($damage_array); ?>";
```

which prints out to:

```
var damages = "{"lf":4,"rf":9,"lrfo":22,"rrfo":19,"lrfi":22,"rrfi":19,"lrro":15,"rrro":10,"lrri":15,"rrri":10}";
```

Can someone please help me clean this out so that my js variable is an actual array?

Comment: try something like this
`<?php echo "var damages = ".json_encode($damage_array); ?>;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
var damagesAsString = '<?php echo json_encode($damage_array); ?>'; // json string
var damages = JSON.parse(damagesAsString); // json object
```

Comment: The one you posted before this one worked better, it returns {"lf":4,"rf":9,"lrfo":22,"rrfo":19,"lrfi":22,"rrfi":19,"lrro":15,"rrro":10,"lrri":15,"rrri":10}, why did you change?

Comment: JSON.parse() parses string to json object. Do you want string or object as result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do this... 
`var damages = <?php echo json_encode($damage_array); ?>;`